# HTML: Significance of Label Name for Radio-Controlled Font Awesome Icons

Tags: html

Pardon me if this ends up being an easy Google. I might be searching the wrong things.

I want to control a set of six uniquely-ID'ed divs inside a section by clicking on a set of Font Awesome icons which trigger hidden radio icons. The printed code works as needed, but I wonder: Why does removing **name="panels"** break icon but not panel functionality, such that all newly clicked FA icons turn red but none reset to black (whereas the specified panel still displays as normal), when nothing explicitly cites **name** and this is the only radio set on my site? All relevant code is shown below. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_a" value="posts" name="panels" checked/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_b" value="cntac" name="panels"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_c" value="about" name="panels"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_d" value="more1" name="panels"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_e" value="more2" name="panels"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="button_f" value="more3" name="panels"/>

<ul id="ctrl">
    <label for="button_a" class="label_a" title="posts"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></label>
    <label for="button_b" class="label_b" title="cntac"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></label>
    <label for="button_c" class="label_c" title="about"><i class="fas fa-feather"></i></label>
    <label for="button_d" class="label_d" title="more1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
    <label for="button_e" class="label_e" title="more2"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></label>
    <label for="button_f" class="label_f" title="more3"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
</ul>

<section><div id="panel_SPECIFIER">Six six uniquely-ID'ed panels in total.</div></section>
```

CSS:

```
#ctrl i {color:black;}

#button_a:checked ~ .label_a i,
#button_b:checked ~ .label_b i,
#button_c:checked ~ .label_c i,
#button_d:checked ~ .label_d i,
#button_e:checked ~ .label_e i, 
#button_f:checked ~ .label_f i{cursor: default;color:red;}
```

jQuery (modeled from [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/show-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-selection-in-jquery.php)):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("#panel_" + inputValue);
        $("section div").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood the question.
I have now adjusted the code so that labels are not in the input.

For that you have * in CSS so that he can use on your label comes out.

Then everything works normally.

**Name**

Inputs with the same value for the name attribute belong to the same group. Only one Input in a group can be selected at a time.

```css
#ctrl i {color:black;}

#button_a:checked ~ * .label_a i,
#button_b:checked ~ * .label_b i,
#button_c:checked ~ * .label_c i,
#button_d:checked ~ * .label_d i,
#button_e:checked ~ * .label_e i, 
#button_f:checked ~ * .label_f i{cursor: default;color:red;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_a" value="posts" name="panels" checked/>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_b" value="cntac" name="panels"/>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_c" value="about" name="panels"/>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_d" value="more1" name="panels"/>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_e" value="more2" name="panels"/>
        <input hidden type="radio" id="button_f" value="more3" name="panels"/>
    

        <ul id="ctrl">
            <label for="button_a" class="label_a" title="posts"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></label>
            <label for="button_b" class="label_b" title="cntac"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></label>
            <label for="button_c" class="label_c" title="about"><i class="fas fa-feather"></i></label>
            <label for="button_d" class="label_d" title="more1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label>
            <label for="button_e" class="label_e" title="more2"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></label>
            <label for="button_f" class="label_f" title="more3"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
        </ul>
    </form>

        <section>
            <div id="panel_SPECIFIER">Six six uniquely-ID'ed panels in total.</div>
        </section>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the snipped code and I have a reason to keep inputs and labels separated. I'm just curious what the importance of <input NAME="XXX"> is, since removing it causes all FA icons to keep their new color if clicked once.

Comment: In response to the new edit: Thanks for that suggested CSS! So does lack of a "name" mean all such inputs think themselves part of different groups rather than as part of an unnamed group?

Comment: I would see it like that